# Window Server Backup products: Are they a viable replacement for SQL-Server backups yet?

Tags: sql-server, backup, veeam, cohesity

We currently use VEEAM for Server level backups including snapshots. We also take full Db and TX logs backups. Most db's are in full recovery mode.

We're about to move to Cohesity for server backups. They have a SQL agent and claim they can do SQL backups. I'm not sure what they really offer, and if it's a true and fair replacement for conventional SQL backups.

Have these products progressed to the point where they are valid and viable replacement? In what scenarios would you use these? Interested to hear from anyone who has investigated this in depth.

What am I missing? what do they know that i don't?

Comment: As far as I'm aware (will stand corrected if wrong) these various "backup/recovery" applications (like Veeam, Cohesity, etc.) are still ultimately triggering a "SQL Backup" within SQL Server, it's just that the output of the backups is being streamed to their own "virtual" devices, and then managed/stored by the application itself.  I guess, ultimately, they give you a centralised management centre for backup/recovery/archive, etc., without the specific need for a SQL DBA to create and schedule all of the necessary things within SQL Server

Comment: I work for a very large international company, and corporate IT decided that SQL Server backups should be written to disk via SQL Server, and Cohesity will "grab & store" the backup files. Something like that, the point being the backup is still being performed directly from SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'm not a fan of 3rd party solutions outside of the database system (this doesn't include Ola Hallengren's scripts) handling backups. Even Veeam I've had very poor experiences with for two reasons:

1. It has options that just don't make sense and are easy to accidentally turn on when you're a System Admin who doesn't know any better as opposed to a DBA who would. An example of this is there's a setting to delete the Transaction Log backup files it just created, when the database is in Full Recovery Model. And it doesn't even warn you that this is nonsensical and risks your Recovery Point Objective (RPO) by getting rid of your ability to do point-in-time recovery. There's no point in this option. The database Recovery Model should be switched to Simple instead of Full, if you don't want point-in-time recovery.
2. There used to be (a few years ago, hopefully has gotten better now) some bugs with Veeam not communicating it successfully made the backup to VMware which caused the back up file to exponentially grow each day the backup process ran again. This eventually caused degradation to the disk where the backups were stored which eventually got unwieldy big, and caused a Purple Screen of Death with VMware. We were on with dedicated support from VMware for 2 days straight resolving the problem.

I've seen both of these occur in production, only in the last few years of my time as a DBA. So I now manage the database backups directly within the database myself.

Comment: Yep. Agreed. I use Ola's scripts. and TBF they just help schedule and call default SQL features. There are 3rd party db backup product like Redgate which i'm sure are good, but i'm particularly interested in the db specific features integrated into Server backup products.

Answer (score 1):

```
Database != File
```

Remember, most of what your DBMS does happens *in memory* within the running *process*, not in its Data Files.

For Database Tasks, use Database Tools.
For File System tasks, use File System tools.
**Do not** try to mix and match them.

That said, SQL Server does have a well documented API that effectively "freezes" the database, preventing it from writing to its Data Files while some, external agent copies those files as part of a "backup".
Do not blindly expect *any* other DBMS to have the same feature.  If any claims to, test it thoroughly.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment. But if that's true, why are the vendors offering DB related features? Surely they must have some confidence in their own products before they would offer this? My gut feel is they must have *some* capability, but I don't where the line gets drawn. Maybe these tools are appropriate for express dbs packaged with apps for static config? But not for highly volatile transactional data.

Comment: If you use standard tools, used by other DBAs the world over, then you have a /huge/ community of experience to draw on if (and when) things go wrong.  
If you're tied to one, proprietary solution that many/most DBAs have never heard of, then you have only that provider to turn to if/when things go awry.  
Principle of Least Surprise - especially at stupid o'clock in the morning when you're trying to get your Production database back up and running after some outage.

Answer (score 1):

We moved to Cohesity for server backups last year. There is a one day online course they run specifically for backing up SQL Server. I seem to remember there are a number of options from just using Cohesity as a share, though various VSS options (which I like to avoid) to a VDI based option which does not require VSS. A lot of the options, including the VDI-based one, require the use of a RestAPI. I found the PowerShell documentation for the RestAPIs to be obscure and to not have any examples.

Of course, when I tried to look at Cohesity the biggest problem I had was getting sufficient rights from our sysadmin just to connect! It took me two days just to get Connect-CohesityCluster to work with my credentials never mind trying to get them to setup service accounts etc. I managed to get some basic backups and restores to work but again ran into permissions problems when trying to do anything more complicated. I then ran out of time and enthusiasm. I might look at Cohesity again but currently SQL Server still backs up to the shares which are then backed up to Cohesity. ie I suspect the biggest problem DBAs have with any of these solutions is getting the correct access to the software.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. :)